# How to convert SqlExpression<T> into SqlExpression<TU> with ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I need to work with `SqlExpression<T>` in a private method but the result should be `SqlExpression<TU>` (due to my project context).
T and TU aims same structure (`TU` is a subset of `T` with some computed expressions)
I didn't find a way to convert `SqlExpression<T>` into `SqlExpression<TU>`.

In following code T = Product class and TU = Powder class.

```
// Sample code
private static SqlExpression<Powder> CreateDefaultExpression(IDbConnection db, IPowderListFilter request)
{
    var ev = db.From<Product>()
    // Joins are set here...
            .Select(p => new
            {
                CustomRalId = Sql.As(p.CustomRalId, nameof(Powder.CustomRalId)),
                Mass = Sql.As(Sql.Sum(p.Width * p.Height / 1000000) * 2 * Settings.LacqueringGramsPerSquareMeter / 1000, nameof(Powder.Mass))
            });

    // I need to do something like...
    ev.ConvertTo<SqlExpression<Powder>>();
    // or ...
    return new SqlExpression<Powder>(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can’t, the typed SqlExpression is a query builder that you can’t just change the Type of and have it automatically erase and reapply all the mutations to the query builder using a different Type.

If reuse is the goal you’d need to use standard C# to DRY as much code as possible which won’t be much since all lambda expressions is typed to a different Type.